# How to sort posts in admin by name

Tags: posts, wp-admin, sort

I have created a multiple posts on my blog and now I want to sort them, for example, by name.

But as I see, the post with the newest ID is always on top of the list and I cannot sort the posts in the queue.

I tried to install some plugins as Change Post Order or Re-Order Post but when I try to sort post with them - sorting is not taking effect.

Is there a way to sort post in other way than by their ID?

[image: Posts sorting in my panel]

Comment: If you click a column (like Data, or ID), it should sort by the column you clicked.

Answer (score 1):

As u put a screenshot from admin in your question I assume you are trying to sort the order from posts within admin area.

Besides, u didn't say anything about whether u want to change the order of the posts for good or u want just to see your posts in a certain order temporarily.

So, I'll leave here a simple solution in order for u to see your posts sorted the way u want (temporarily) just changing the URL.

Suppose you are seeing, in admin, the page that lists your pages, which has the following URI:

`/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page`

So, if you want to order your posts by name u just change your URI to:

`/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page&orderby=name&order=desc`

OR

`/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page&orderby=name&order=asc`

I suppose u know that the 'name' in WordPress is related to the 'slug'. And the title is actually what is related to the post title. But, at the end, this will only make difference if some or all of your posts have a slug different from their title.

Anyway, if u want to order them by title u need to change to:

`/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page&orderby=title&order=desc`

> If u want to see more values u could use for the paramater `orderby` u should take a look at: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Answer (score 0):

Just change order "ASC" to "DESC" in your own code, it will work perfectly. Or copy and paste below mentioned code into your functions.php :

```
 function post_order_in_admin( $wp_query ) {

global $pagenow;

if ( is_admin() && 'edit.php' == $pagenow && !isset($_GET['orderby'])) {

    $wp_query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
    $wp_query->set( 'order', 'DESC' );       
}
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'post_order_in_admin', 5 );
```